# Example of how to use UWP NavigationView in Prism 7.2

Tags: uwp, prism

I have been using a variation of the Template 10 approach to using `NavigationView`.  See [Alternative way to create shell in Prism.Windows 7.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926892/alternative-way-to-create-shell-in-prism-windows-7-1-0/53229031#53229031)

With the `Prism 7.2 pre-release`, the call to `NavigationService.Create` does not seem to be available.

My goal is to allow navigation using the `UWP` `NavigationView` and `Prism 7.2`. I having been banging my head against this without success but hopefully there is a simple solution I am missing?

[Update] 21 Mar 2019: Prism support for UWP has been abandoned pending reassessment of the path forward. See https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1745

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one having an issue with this, see the [related question on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1685#issuecomment-464367432).

The `Create` method was removed, but you can now create `NavigationService` using the `CreateNavigationService` method in `PrismApplicationBase` (see [code on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/d4768773d11afff19bb1ad5a551a3165fa002640/Source/Windows10/Prism.Windows/PrismApplicationBase.cs#L190)). It has the same arguments so you should be able to use it instead of the `Create` method you have been using up to this point.

Comment: Thanks.  I had trouble implementing this in my control as I could not get access to the method.  I shall see what comes of the GitHub question.